# Enviar json do iphone para um dispositivo Bluetooth

Tags: json, ios, xcode, bluetooth

Estou precisando criar um app que envia uma informação json (login e senha) para um dispositivo bluetooth, que ira consultar em um banco de dados e ver se o login e a senha estão corretos. Tenho este app para android e estou querendo desenvolver para iOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132174/ios-recieve-data-from-bluetooth-and-then-send-information-to-a-database-on-anoth